# multiprocessing uses all cores for the same code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list of tuples which are used inside a loop to perform some calculations. The calculations can take some time, hence I want to try to divide the tasks over multiple processing cores (to speed things up). Something goes wrong here.

First of all: I checked the performance of each of the cores when I run the code and all cores are used, but it seems that (based on the results) the same calculation is performed for each of the cores. For example: if I want to do 1+1, 2+2 and 3+3, I want to make sure one core does 1+1, one core does 2+2 and another core does 3+3. Now all three cores do 1+1, 2+2 and 3+3 (so I get the results three times then).

The second thing is that I checked the calculation time and with multiprocessing takes more time than without multiprocessing, which shouldn't happen I think.

I made a small code example below. All calculations that take some time are performed under the for-loop in the function 'func' and this is the part where I want to use more CPU cores. The example code can be tested directly and the list is reduced to the first 20 iterations so that it does not take too long (adjust this if needed).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np
import itertools
import time
import math

def func(list_products):
    
    # for i in range(len(list_total_product)):
    for i in range(len(list_products)):
        
        # Perform calculations
        i

""" Creating the list """
# Input
item1_deviation = 1 #%
item1_steps = 10

item2_deviation = 10 #%
item2_N = 3 # minimum of 2


# Create first list
item1_base = 360
item1_deviation_rounded = item1_base * (item1_deviation / 100)
list_item1s = np.arange(item1_base - item1_deviation_rounded,
                                item1_base + item1_deviation_rounded+item1_deviation,
                                item1_steps).tolist()
list_item1s = [int(math.ceil(item / item1_steps)) * item1_steps for item in list_item1s]


# Create second list
item2_base = 0.77
list_item2s = np.linspace(item2_base - (item2_base * (item2_deviation / 100)),
                         item2_base + (item2_base * (item2_deviation / 100)),
                         item2_N).tolist()
list_item2s = [round(item, 3) for item in list_item2s]


# Create the number of combinations
list_total_sequence = []
for i in range(6):
    
    list_sequence = [list_item1s, list_item2s]
    list_product = list(itertools.product(*list_sequence))
    
    list_total_sequence.append(list_product)
    
list_total_product = list(itertools.product(*list_total_sequence))



""" Without Multiprocessing """
t1 = time.perf_counter()

# for i in range(len(list_total_product)):
for i in range(len(list_total_product[0:20])):
    
    # Perform calculations
    i

t2 = time.perf_counter()

print(t2-t1)



""" With Multiprocessing """
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    p = Process(target=func, args=(list_total_product[0:20],))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
        
    print(t2-t1)
```

One can enable/disable the code under "Without Multiprocessing" and "With Multiprocessing"

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: suggested by @diedthreetimes

I think I understand it, but this also seems not to work properly.

Thus I have the following code, thanks to diedthreetimes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    processes = []
    num_cores = 1
    num_items = 700
    num_items_per_core = int(num_items / num_cores) # = 5; watch for rounding errors
    ipc = num_items_per_core
    
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    for i in range(0, num_cores):
        p = Process(target=func, args=(list_total_product[ipc*i:ipc*i+ipc],))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
        
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    
    print(t2-t1)
```

You can see I changed the num_items to 700 ans using one core only. This takes around 0.183 seconds. Running the same code in a for-loop without multiprocessing lasts 3.68e-05 seconds. Now it obvouisly doesn't matter, but the actual code is more time consuming and there this will matter quite a lot.

Comment: You only create one process?!

Comment: `multiprocessing` provides `Pool` class to distribute such tasks easily.

Comment: Joining a process directly after it was started usually make no sense.

Comment: Your test calculation is so short that the cost of creating processes and the communication needed to pass and return values completely dwarfs the calculation. Parallelziation is only worth while if the calculations themselves are relatively large.

Answer (score 0):

You only created one process object, and therefore you only are running on a single process. `multiprocessing` doesn't handle task distribution automatically.

If you want to create multiple processes you need create multiple process objects. Something like:

```
processes = []
num_cores = 4
num_items = 20
num_items_per_core = num_items / num_cores # = 5; watch for rounding errors
ipc = num_items_per_core

for i in range(0, num_cores):
    p = Process(target=func, args=(list_total_product[ipc*i:ipc*i+ipc],))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
for p in processes
    p.join()
```

Here I've tried to execute your function four times, in four processes, each with a slice of size `ipc` in this case 5. i.e. Proc `i` is assigned a slice `i` from `[0:5]`, `[5:10]`, `[10:15]`, `[15:20]`.

However, it's important to note that your Operating System's scheduler could still place two processes on the same core. A fix for this is OS specific and out side the scope of this answer.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion. Multiprocessing still takes more time than not using it. This doesn't matter for this small code, but the actual code requires heavy calculations in the for loop, hence there it will make a difference. I updated the question with your suggestion. Will I see the effect of this only when I use the actual (and more heavy) code?

Comment: If you only have one core you should expect the program to run slower. There is considerable overhead in multiprocessing and for a small example like this that overhead will dominate the measurement.

Comment: Well as long as it will perform these calculations at the same time using multiple cores, then I'm happy.